# custom output when control-c is used to exit python script

Tags: python, error-handling

I would like the user to use control-c to close a script, but when control-c is pressed it shows the error and reason for close (which make sense). Is there a way to have my own custom output to the screen rather than what is shown? Not sure how to handle that specific error.

Comment: [signal handling?](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `try..except` to catch KeyboardInterrupt:

```
import time

def main():
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('bye')
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [signal module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/signal.html) to define a handler for the SIGINT signal:

```
import signal
import sys

def sigint_handler(signal_number, stack_frame):
    print('caught SIGINT, exiting')
    sys.exit(-1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
raw_input('waiting...')
```

Answer (score 0):

For general purpose code, handling the KeyboardInterrupt should suffice.  For advanced code, such as threading, it is a whole different story.  Here's a simple example.

## http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt

```
try:
    while 1:
        x = raw_input("Type something or press CTRL+C to end: ")
        print repr(x)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "\nWe're done here."
```