# How to stop/terminate a python script from running? (once again)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Context**:

I have a running python script. It contains many `os.system("./executableNane")` calls in a loop.

If I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, it just stops the execution of the current `./executableNane` and passes to the next one.

**Question**:

How to stop the execution of the whole script and not only the execution of the current executable called?

**Please note** that I have read carefully the question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782075/how-to-stop-terminate-a-python-script-from-running/34029481) but even with `kill` I can kill the executable *executableNane* but not the whole script (that I cannot find using `top`).

The only way I have to stop the script (without reboot the system) is to continue to press ctrl + C in a loop as well until all the tests are completed.

Comment: Try using subprocess.popen()?

Comment: not from within the script but from outside

Comment: Try ctrl-break.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, sorry for my ignorance. What is "break"? is a button on my keyboard?

Comment: Yes, on my keyboard it is combined with the pause key and is near the printscreen and scroll lock keys.  Not all keyboards have it.  My desktop has it, but laptop doesn't, but it is a "harder" break than ctrl-c.

Comment: pgrep/pkill for python or your executable ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key mentions alternatives if your keyboard doesn't support it.

Comment: Please see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34779671/6045800) might help. It is about defining a handler for `SIGINT`. I used a similar technique to stop all running processes at once in a `multiprocessing.Pool`. Not sure how it works using `os.system` though... But might be a lead for you

Comment: the only way I have to stop the script (without reboot the system) is to continue to press `ctrl + C` in a loop as well, until all the tests are completed. Updating the question

Comment: If your PID is 123, `kill -2 -123` with a negative PID will signal the entire process group.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, tested the key combination you were suggesting and it does work.

Comment: consider using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) instead of `os.system`

Comment: @Tomerikoo, reading now about that option!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and [signal handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) to do this. You can also use `subprocess` to receive and send information via `subprocess.PIPE`, which you can read more about in the documentation.

The following should be a basic example of what you are looking to do:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print("You pressed Ctrl+C, stopping.")
    print("Signal: {}".format(sig))
    print("Frame: {}".format(frame))

    sys.exit(123)

# Set up signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

print("Starting.")
while True:
    cmd = ['sleep', '10']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    p.wait()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        print("Command failed.")
    else:
        print("Command worked.")
```

Comment: +1 I will try the solution as soon I will come back to the yestarday problem on the other project I am working on!

Comment: @Leos313 I can't comment on your answer due to rep, but `Ctrl-Z` pauses the execution of your program rather than stops it. 

Because `os.system()` is a blocking call, your Python process is waiting for the `executableName` process to finish. You are suspending the currently running `executableName` process so your Python process is still waiting for it to finish. 

If you resume the process with `bg` or `fg` the process will resume exactly where you left off. Keep in mind that no cleanup will have happened with Ctrl-Z because the process hasn't exited (files still open, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

The other solution to the question (by @Quillan Kaseman) is much more elegant compared with the solution I have found. All my problems are solved when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Indeed, I have no idea why with `Z` works and with `C` does not. (I will try to look for some details later on).